# Service binding using intent filter

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I'm having trouble binding my activity to my service application using intent filters.

Here is a snippet from what I have to connect to my service application:

```
// The connection to the service.
private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection()
{
    // When the messenger gets bound to the service.
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Attached");
        messenger = new Messenger(binder);
    }

    // When the messenger gets unbound from the service.
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className)
    {
        messenger = null;
    }
};

// Bind the service connection with the service application.
private void createServiceBinding()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "binding service.");
    activity.bindService(new Intent(this.activity, TestService.class), this.connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    this.isBound = true;
}
```

This works just find. I am able to send and receive Messages using a Messenger. However, I need to be able to call activity.bindService with the intent filter of my service application rather than TestService.class.

How do I bind the activity to the service application using intent filter (e.g. com.example.testapplication.TestService rather than TestService.class)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: here is a good tutorial : http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android

Comment: Post the part of your manifest containing the `<service>` tag

Answer (score 2):

> However, I need to be able to call activity.bindService with the intent filter of my service application rather than TestService.class.

More accurately, you *want* to be able to call `bindService()` with an `Intent` that matches the `<intent-filter>` of your service.

Unless you are planning on third party apps binding to your service, please stick with your existing approach and remove the `<intent-filter>` from the service. It is not necessary (as you have seen) and it exports your service by default.

> How do I bind the activity to the service application using intent filter (e.g. com.example.testapplication.TestService rather than TestService.class)?

Use a different `Intent` constructor, plus perhaps other setters on the `Intent` object, to configure it to match your `<intent-filter>`. Since you decided not to provide your `<intent-filter>`, we cannot give you specific instructions.

If, for example, your `<intent-filter>` looked like:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.troje.this.is.probably.a.bad.IDEA"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

then your `Intent` would be created via `new Intent("com.troje.this.is.probably.a.bad.IDEA")` to use to bind to the service.